# Recursively filter nested tree

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this tree structure. I want to filter those items with friends. For example I would like to get all object with friends = FRIEND_3 only, I would like to keep the tree structure.

For example, this is my complete base tree (Here there is only 3 levels of hierarchy, but it is variable I can have more or less) :

```
[
  {
    "name": "BASE_PARENT_1",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "SUB_PARENT_1",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "CHILDREN_1",
            "friends": [
              {
                "name": "FRIEND_1",
                "description": "Lorem ipsum"
              },
              {
                "name": "FRIEND_2",
                "description": "Lorem ipsum",
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "SUB_PARENT_2",
        "children": [
            ..etc
        ]
      },
      ...etc
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "BASE_PARENT_2",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "SUB_PARENT_1_2",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "CHILDREN_1",
            "friends": [
              {
                "name": "FRIEND_1",
                "description": "Lorem ipsum"
              },
              {
                "name": "FRIEND_3",
                "description": "Lorem ipsum"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "SUB_PARENT_2_2",
        "children": [
            ..etc
        ]
      },
      ...etc
    ]
  }
]
```

If I filter with FRIEND_3, I would like to have this result :

```
[
  {
    "name": "BASE_PARENT_2",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "SUB_PARENT_1_2",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "CHILDREN_1",
            "friends": [
              {
                "name": "FRIEND_3",
                "description": "Lorem ipsum"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

In other words, I want to filter parent if it has no children containing a Friend after the filter

I tried something like this:

```
function filterTree(tree, friendName) {
  const filtered = tree.filter(node => {
    if (node.friends) {
      return node.friends.some(friend => friend.name === friendName);
    } else if (node.children) {
      node.children = filterTree(node.children, friendName);
      return node.children.length > 0;
    }
    return false;
  });
  return filtered;
}
```

but it returns all friends and not only the friend I want to filter

Comment: What is your approach to solve this problem?

Comment: I have updated my question with what I just tried

Comment: Do you want to filter in place (manipulate the tree) or get a new tree?

Comment: I want to get a new tree @pmoleri

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `.map()` and `.filter()`. First use `.map` to create the target for each entry in the array, or `false` (or any falsy value) when it should be excluded. Then call `.filter()` on that result array to exclude the falsy elements from it. This can be done with chaining a `.filter(Boolean)`.

So taking your code, a few changes are needed to make it work:

```js
function filterTree(tree, friendName) {
  return tree.map(node => {
    if (node.friends) {
      const friends = node.friends.filter(friend => friend.name === friendName);
      return friends.length && { ...node, friends };
    } else if (node.children) {
      const children = filterTree(node.children, friendName);
      return children.length && {...node, children };
    }
    return false;
  }).filter(Boolean);
}

// Example from the question:
const tree = [{"name": "BASE_PARENT_1","children": [{"name": "SUB_PARENT_1","children": [{"name": "CHILDREN_1","friends": [{"name": "FRIEND_1","description": "Lorem ipsum"},{"name": "FRIEND_2","description": "Lorem ipsum",}]}]},{"name": "SUB_PARENT_2","children": []},]},{"name": "BASE_PARENT_2","children": [{"name": "SUB_PARENT_1_2","children": [{"name": "CHILDREN_1","friends": [{"name": "FRIEND_1","description": "Lorem ipsum"},{"name": "FRIEND_3","description": "Lorem ipsum"}]}]},{"name": "SUB_PARENT_2_2","children": []},]}]
const result = filterTree(tree, "FRIEND_3");
console.log(result);
```